Is there a way to retrieve data from postgres in node using pg that can be stored in a variable and used outside pg.end()?
Every time I try to access the data stored in the variable I get an empty array. Is there a way around this? I have tried using pg.Pool but it didn't work. I was expecting the numberOfUsers variable to contain the result from the query. This is the code
enter image description here
const userDb = new pg.Client({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "Project DB",
  password: "1567tay",
  port: 5432,
});

userDb.connect();

function userNameCount(userName){
  let numberOfUsers = [];
  
  userDb.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = $1", [userName], (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error executing query", err.stack);
    } else {
      numberOfUsers = res.rows;
    }
    userDb.end();
  });
  return numberOfUsers;
}

